# Copying and modifying a default theme

Tags: r, themes, plot, ggplot2

I would like to create a new theme for `ggplot` that is based on `theme_bw()`.

I imagine the following steps are necessary (in pseudocode):

1. Make a copy of theme_bw(): `theme_new() <- theme_bw()`
2. Modify the copy: `theme_update(axis.title.x = theme_text(family = base_family, size = base_size, vjust = 0.5))`

Any advice on how to implement this will be very much appreciated!

---

**Edit:** @Andrie, I modified your answer for my needs:

```
theme_new <- theme_set(theme_bw())
theme_new <- theme_update(axis.title.x = theme_text(family = base_family, size = base_size, vjust = 0.5))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar()
```

> Error in match(gparname, names(gpars)) : object 'base_size' not found

---

**Edit:** 31/10/2017, answer provided by @Andrie works just fine.
*R version 3.4.1, ggplot2_2.2.1*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the [wiki](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Themes) suggests one way to do this using `modifyList`,

```
theme_new <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "", ...){
 modifyList (theme_bw (base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family),
          list (axis.title.x = theme_text(family = base_family, 
                size = base_size, vjust = 0.5)))
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked! I tried this before, but I didn't figure out the `base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family` part and always got the error `Error in match(gparname, names(gpars)) : object 'base_size' not found`.

Comment: note: this is now redundant with the new theming system introduced in ggplot2 0.9.

Comment: [Link describing the new theming system and describing how to modify it.](https://github.com/wch/ggplot2/wiki/New-theme-system)

Answer (score 25):

Your code just needs a few small changes to work (mainly removing brackets and adding brackets at the right places)

```
theme_new <- theme_set(theme_bw())

theme_new <- theme_update(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill="lightblue"))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

---

Reference:

- [CRAN: extending-ggplot2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html)
- [Tidyverse: themes](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/#section-themes)
- [GitHub: New-theme-system](https://github.com/wch/ggplot2/wiki/New-theme-system)

Comment: Running similar code worked for me (thank you) but I wonder why `theme_new()` can't be added at the end of the `ggplot` sequence as one might do with `theme_bw()`? More precisely `ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar() + theme_new()` returns error `Error in theme_new() : could not find function "theme_new"`.

Answer (score 6):

For the newer versions, based on the article [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html)

```
txt <- element_text(size = 14, colour = "black", face = "plain")
bold_txt <- element_text(size = 14, colour = "black", face = "bold")

theme_whatever <- function(base_size = 14, base_family = "Palatino")
{
  theme_bw(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) +
  theme(
    legend.key = element_blank(), 
    strip.background = element_blank(), 

    text = txt, 
    plot.title = txt, 

    axis.title = txt, 
    axis.text = txt, 

    legend.title = bold_txt, 
    legend.text = txt ) 
}
```

Note that I use `txt` and `txt_bold` to avoid writing same stuff over and over again.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this one:

```
### Set up a blank theme
theme_none <- theme(
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  panel.background = element_blank(),
  axis.title.x = element_text(colour=NA),
  axis.title.y = element_blank(),
  axis.text.x = element_blank(),
  axis.text.y = element_blank(),
  axis.line = element_blank()
  #axis.ticks.length = element_blank()
)
```