# How to make a default custom theme with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

When I try to apply a custom made theme using `ggplot2` it get an error like:

```
Error in FUN("text"[[1L]], ...) : 
  Theme element 'text' has NULL property: family, face, size, hjust, vjust, angle, lineheight
```

I think I must miss something basic here (my first try on creating custom themes).
The theme was created based on `theme_bw()`:

```
theme_new <- function(base_size = 12, base_family = "Helvetica"){
    theme_bw(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace%
    theme(
        line = element_line(colour="black"),
        text = element_text(colour="black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.text = element_text(colour="black", size=8),
        strip.text = element_text(size=12),
        legend.key=element_rect(colour=NA, fill =NA),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),   
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black", size=1),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"), 
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = NA)
        )
    }
```

Then try it out:

> x <- rnorm(10)
>
> theme_set(theme_new())
>
> qplot(x)

Get the above error!

However:

> theme_set(theme_bw())
>
> qplot(x)

Works fine!

I guess that the theme_update described in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459796/ggplot2-how-can-one-copy-a-default-theme-and-modify-it) is not the same as changing the default theme with theme_set().
If we look at the new theme guidelines in this the vignette (http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html) my understanding is that one EITHER need to specify all theme parameters and use the `complete=TRUE` to tell this; OR use the    `%+replace%`operator to add something to an old theme, like theme_bw().
Dont get it though!

Answer (score 7):

Brief glimpse over http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html reveals

> Therefore, when using the %+replace% operator to create a new theme function, you need to be very careful about replacing theme elements at the top of the inheritance hierarchy such as text, line and rect.
>
> ...
>
> Notice that the theme elements replaced in theme_bw primarily have NULL properties in theme_grey() since most of the default properties in the latter are defined in elements rect, line and text and passed down to their child elements. The %+replace% operator is used to set non-NULL properties in the selected elements specified in theme() with all undeclared properties set to NULL.

So, you should comment out the specifications including `line`, `text`, `rect` since they were already defined in the parent themes: `theme_bw` and `theme_grey`.

```
theme_new <- function(base_size = 12, base_family = "Helvetica"){
  theme_bw(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace%
    theme(
      #line = element_line(colour="black"),
      #text = element_text(colour="black"),
      axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
      #axis.text = element_text(colour="black", size=8),
      #strip.text = element_text(size=12),
      legend.key=element_rect(colour=NA, fill =NA),
      panel.grid = element_blank(),   
      panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black", size=1),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"), 
      strip.background = element_rect(fill = NA)
      )
}
```

`qplot(x) + theme_new()` produces the following image with bunch of warnings related to the fonts.
[image]

When on different machine, it produced virtually any plots I tried without any warnings, so I guess it works!
For instance, the second set of plots in http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Scatterplots_(ggplot2)/ is reproduced as[image]

Comment: with all these warnings this cannot be a solution. Anyway it doesnt work when you do another plot.

Comment: I am curious to know what particular plot you can't produce with it. Take a look at edited version of the answer.

Comment: Yes it helped removing the lines with "basic" settings (although its not entirely clear why this is so), and I guess the warnings all are related to a missing windows font which could easily be fixed.