# Is there a ggplot one liner to completely delete the x-axis and all associated components?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I often plot graphs that don't have an x-axis. The ggplot code often looks something like this:

```
library(ggplot)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),  # line 5
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),  # line 6
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),  # line 7
        axis.line.x = element_blank())  # line 8
```

Is there one line I can use to replace lines five through seven? I'm constantly plotting these graphs and looking for something less lengthy to type.

[image: ggplot no x-axis]

Comment: You can create a theme, see [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400931/how-to-make-a-default-custom-theme-with-ggplot2-in-r) or [R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/custom-themes-in-ggplot2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not difficult to create a theme with the definitions the user wants. I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400931/how-to-make-a-default-custom-theme-with-ggplot2-in-r) and this [R-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/custom-themes-in-ggplot2/) useful.
Note that in the example there is no need for `theme_classic()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

theme_no_x_axis <- function(base_size = 12, base_family = "Helvetica"){
  theme_bw(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace%
    theme(
      axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
      axis.line.x = element_blank()
    )
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_no_x_axis()
```

[image]

Comment: What does `%+replace%` do? I've never seen that before. Thank you.

Comment: @JasonHunter From R-bloggers: *we can create a new theme as a function calling an existing theme, which is altered by %+replace% theme() with all alterations defined in theme().*.

Comment: @JasonHunter I changed the example to the `mtcars` example in the question, like I should have posted in the first place.

Comment: I actually did want the `theme_classic()` look, but your answer still is great.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new them and use that theme instead:

```
newtheme <- theme_classic() + 
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),  # line 5
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),  # line 6
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),  # line 7
          axis.line.x = element_blank())  # line 8

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
    geom_point() +
    newtheme
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set the breaks at ridiculous positions and the name to `NULL` and it won't show.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = -Inf, name = NULL)
```

[image]

You could also make a wrapper for it if you want it even shorter.

```
scale_x_null <- function() {
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = -Inf, name = NULL)
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_null()
```

Comment: quite a novel idea and I do like it. Only issue is the `axis.line.x` is plotted if you use `theme_classic()` with your code. Any easy way to fix this? And isn't the new issue I have to write that wrapper into every script and .Rmd file I create? I guess once is better than multiple times. Or do I just make a cheat-sheet.R file with all my custom functions and run `source(cheat-sheet.R)` on every script I create? I could create a package just for short code chunks like this, but that seems excessive.

Comment: Hmm good question, I was using ggplot2 3.1.0 and no line appeared, but when I updated to 3.2.0 the line was there. Would have to backtrace the releases how this was introduced and what could circumvent this. Personally I use a markdown template with all my usual settings in the template itself.

Comment: I couldn't quite figure out what change causes this discrepancy between 3.1.0 and 3.2.0, however I did found an interesting pull request on the ggplot2 github that would allow you to set position guides (i.e. x-axis) to custom guides, including non-existing guides. Guess you kinda got unlucky with 3.2.0 since both the versions before and versions after would have a solution. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3398

Comment: when you say the version "after" do you mean the future, not released yet version? I just `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")` installed and the latest version is `ggplot2_3.2.0.9000`.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, sorry

Comment: and why use `-Inf` when `Inf` seems to work just as well and is one less keystroke? Any compelling reason?

Comment: The first attempt had -1e6, which I changed to -Inf, the minus sign stuck. I guess Inf would be better when a log-transform is applied since `log10(-Inf)` is evaluated as `NaN` and `log10(Inf)` is evaluated as `Inf`.

Comment: When the pull request is complete what will be the argument I should add to your code to remove the `axis.line.x`? https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3398

Comment: I would assume it would be `+ scale_x_continuous(guide = guide_none())` based on the syntax posted in that pull request under details, but it would be too early to say for sure. But that would be to replace `+ scale_x_null()`/`+scale_x_continuous(breaks = Inf, name = NULL)`, not to add to it.

Comment: Thanks I like this answer the best but unfortunately I have to wait until it actually works. Cheers.