# ggplot axis.title description in one line function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem with my own function.
I mean, I create a function in which arguments will be name of axis.title.

```
describe_axis <- function(x_axis, y_axis){
  y <- y_axis
  x <- x_axis
    xlab(x)+
    ylab(y)
}
```

If I use it in normal ggplot code:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, qsec))+
   geom_point()+
   describe_axis("X-axis","Y-axis")
```

I get an error `non-numeric argument to binary operator`.
How to manage with it?

Comment: As noted in the help files `?"+.gg"`, the ggplot2 `+` operator works only if the first object is class `ggplot` or `theme`. One possible alternative is the following: `add_labs = function(p, x_lab, y_lab) {return(p + xlab(x_lab) + ylab(y_lab))}; p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, qsec)) + geom_point(); add_labs(p, "new x", "new y")`.

Comment: Here is another possible approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4835697/645206

Comment: @bdemarest I have already used the fisrt solution you proposed, but the second one `list` of argument this is what I want to! Thanks a lot for help:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to label your axes:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, qsec))+ geom_point()+ xlab("X-axis") + ylab("Y-axis")
```

Comment: That's fine. But in simple example I would like to know how to manage with  2 part of ggplot code to create one function which figured out this `binary operator` problem. I want to my code above works!

Comment: It's not clear why you would want to do that, additional information would be helpful here.

Comment: Because I wanna to use this analogy to create my own layout named `theme_por()` and join it with my own group of color which replace default color of R

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459796/ggplot2-how-can-one-copy-a-default-theme-and-modify-it

Comment: But still it is not solution of my problem. I know how to create function `theme` but I also want to join e.g. `scale_color_manual` where I define my own color group in the same function, of course when I use `color` arument in `aes`. I only want to know if it possible to create a function's output with two arguments joined by `+` sign.

Comment: @Nicolabo: do you mean you want to declare a fn which uses the ggplot `+` operator to concatenate arbitrarily many fns to a ggplot object? Has that not been solved by the comments above on the question? If not, please clarify the question to explain how?